# I want to reload same page (current page) but with different session parameters

Tags: php, symfony

MAIN PROBLEME
I would like to **change some session parameters** (which are taken into account to display or not some part of my page) **by clicking on a button, but still display the same page**. how can I achieve it?

EXEMPLE
I want the user to change the color of the background of the page. (the background color is stored in session('backgroundcolor').
**How can I do so that when a user click on the 'Green Backgroundcolor' the session get the new value AND the current page** (page where the user was when he clicked on the button) **is being reloaded.**

(the button is in main layout, therefore can be clicked on all the page of the site, which have all different routes of course)

FOR INFO
I use symfony2. I do not want to do it with javascript/jquery because this is an exemple and sometime some other session value changement by user will trigger a BD request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the adaptation for Symfony (adapted from Tyranicangel code which was not adapted to Symfony):

I used a form and posted to the same page (action="" in the form)

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession(); // access to session
if(isset($_POST['backgroundcolor'])) 
{
   $session->set('backgroundcolor',$_POST['backgroundcolor']);
}
```

Comment: You should do $this->getRequest()->request->get('backgroundColor') instead of using $_POST, it's the Symfony way to use GET and POST vars. http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#requetes-et-reponses-dans-symfony

Comment: having two forms on the same page I got some issue using **$this->getRequest()->request** (tocken error of the other form is trigered... and do not know how to separate the two forms in $this->getRequest()...? might be some arguments/parameters to be used?

Comment: I don't see how a token error can be triggered by using $this->getRequest()->request. Hard to tell without the code, but anyway if it works with $_POST that's fine, just not the Symfony standards.

Answer (score -2):

Post to the Same Page and Change the session variable

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['change_color']))
   {
       session_start();
       $_SESSION['backgroundcolor']=$_POST['change_color'];
   }
//continue with your code
?>
```

On click of your button send a post request to the same page.

Comment: symfony2 have a [built-in session system](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) and this answer could generate some unexpected bad result.

Comment: I adapted the answer for symfony2 build in session. working fine.

Comment: @Aleqxs you need to write your own answer with the right code for symfony2 and then accept it because this answer is wrong for symfony's users.

Comment: ok I added the code I used in my site which is adapted for symfony. (code apapted from Tyranicangel 's code